# In Java, during TLS handshake, if a custom X509TrustManager is used, will the peer's signature still be verified

Tags: java, security, tls1.3, jsse, ssl-handshake

Below, I'm describing a super-simplified scenario, just so I won't burden you with details.

If I write a client that communicates with a remote server over HTTPS, and if, during the TLS handshake, I use a custom `X509TrustManager` with a `checkServerTrusted(...)` implementation that simply checks whether the server's certificate exactly matches some pre-defined certificate, and I don't perform any other checks but simply return, will Java's SSL library still verify that the server owns the private key associated with the certificate? In other words, will Java check that the signature, sent by the server, is valid?

I'm expecting that Java will still validate the server's signature.

Comment: Yes it will, this isn't part of the checks required by `checkServerTrusted()`, which only has to do what you described. If the check fails you won't even get to `checkServerTrusted()`.

Comment: @user207421, thank you, this is very helpful. Do you know where in the SSL libraries (OpenJDK or Oracle JDK) is the validation of the signature performed?

Comment: Well somebody calls `certificate.verify()`, but don’t ask me where, I just deleted all my JSSE source code ;-(